# Svelte Component Not Reactive When Using Global Script

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, sveltekit, mapkit-js

I'm using SvelteKit to build an app, and I import an external script (Apple's MapKit JS) in my `app.html` like this:

```js
<script src="https://cdn.apple-mapkit.com/mk/5.72.88/mapkit.js"></script>
```

I then have a `Map.svelte` component that loads a point on a map using my own `Airport` object. I have omitted extra details that aren't relevant with `...`:

```js
// === Map.svelte ===

<script lang="ts">
import { onMount } from 'svelte'
import type { Airport } from '$lib/data/typesAirports'

export let airport:Airport
let mapWrap:HTMLDivElement
let map: mapkit.Map

onMount(() => {
  setupMap(airport)
})

function setupMap(airport){
  //Setup my mapkit object with my token
  mapkit.init(...)

  //Set my map instance
  map = new mapkit.Map(mapWrap, {...})

  //Create pin on map using airport latitude and longitude
  const annotation = new mapkit.MarkerAnnotation(...airport latitude & longitude...)
  map.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
</script>

<!-- Map in HTML -->
<div bind:this={mapWrap}></div>
```

So far, this works great. But when I change my `airport` property in the **parent component**:

```js
//=== Parent.svelte ===

<Map airport={airport} />
```

...there is no reactivity in the `Map` component. My suspicion is this is because things that happen in `onMount` are excluded from that reactivity, but I'm unclear on how that works.

If I try something like this, I get an error that `airport` is `undefined`:

```js
$: setupMap(airport)
```

How can I preserve reactivity in a component like this that relies on an external JS library? Or more specifically, how do I get my map to reload when the `airport` changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onMount` happens once, when the component mounted to the DOM. The approach using a reactive statement is the correct one.

If a property can be uninitialized/undefined you can simply guard against that using an `if` statement:

```js
$: if (airport) setupMap(airport)
```

---

Regarding the loading of external scripts:

I would load them where they are used, ideally using a [dynamic `import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import); this only works for modules though. Imports like this can be awaited in `async` functions or via the `{#await}` directive. [REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/a9bd202235ac49cda83788a1b0896a6b?version=3.48.0)

For non-modules a `<script>` tag can be added dynamically and the `load` event can be used to signal a component that the script can now be used. [REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/c046386927194d0c92429245dce4e1f6?version=3.48.0)

A `<link rel="prefetch" ...>` can be used to speed up the loading of these resources. ([More on prefetching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ))

Comment: Yeah, I had tried guarding against `airport` being `undefined`, but then `mapkit` is not defined. I assume this is because `mapkit` is defined globally and somehow isn't available on the window object yet when `setupMap()` is called.

Comment: Ah, looks like I just need to do a `browser` check as well and firing `setupMap` fires. It was trying to load it on the server side.

Comment: Generally I would not recommend global imports, but instead load the script only where it is needed. If the script is exposed as a module, it can even be loaded with a dynamic `import()` statement and be awaited inside an `async` function. For global `<script>` tags you can use the `load` event and e.g. re-dispatch a custom event or set an attribute on the window which can be used in components.

Comment: If you are worried about delays when loading the script, you can still include a `<link rel="prefetch" ...>` in the root HTML and do the actual import later.

Comment: Can you point me to an example of dynamic loading a script like this?

Comment: [Here is an example](https://svelte.dev/repl/a9bd202235ac49cda83788a1b0896a6b?version=3.48.0). The REPL will automatically preload the script, but in Svelte Kit this will start the request to load the script when the preview is first enabled if there is no prefetching going on. If the imported resource references an NPM module, it will have to be installed of course (the REPL pulls them from `unpkg.com` upon compilation).

Comment: Apple MapKit does  not appear to be available as a module, so you have use a `<script>` tag. [Here would be an example](https://svelte.dev/repl/c046386927194d0c92429245dce4e1f6?version=3.48.0) of adding one dynamically.